# How can I configure in my libgit2 based application?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, config, libgit2

It will prompt: The system file 'gitconfig' doesn't exist
This is my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include "include/git2.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#pragma comment(lib, "git2d.lib")
#else
#pragma comment(lib, "git2.lib")
#endif

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    git_threads_init();

    git_repository* repo = NULL;
    int iRetVal = git_repository_init(&repo, (LPCTSTR)("C:\\test"), false);

    if( (iRetVal < 0) && (giterr_last() != NULL) )
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, giterr_last()->message, "gittest", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
    }
    if( repo != NULL )
        git_repository_free(repo);

    git_threads_shutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

The iRetVal returns -1 and the 'repo' is NULL, but a repository created in C:\test
I know there are three types of config: system, xdg, global, what kind of config and where to place it?

**The second question's code is**:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "include/git2.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "git2.lib")

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    git_threads_init();

    git_repository* repo = NULL;
    git_clone_options opts = GIT_CLONE_OPTIONS_INIT;
    int iRetVal;

    opts.bare = true;
    iRetVal = git_clone(&repo, "https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2.git", "C:\\test", &opts);
    if( (iRetVal < 0) && (giterr_last() != NULL) )
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, giterr_last()->message, "gittest", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
    }
    if( repo != NULL )
        git_repository_free(repo);

    git_threads_shutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is not a fatal error, so it is likely that it's left-over from libgit2 tyring to find configuration. The `LPCTSTR` suggests that you're trying to pass wide chars to libgit2, which wont work, as libgit2 wants a UTF-8 string.

Comment: I deleted (LPCTSTR) and has the same result. And I can't ignore the result, the 'repo' returns NULL and I can't use it.

Comment: The cast itself isn't so much the problem, but an indication that the data you have regardless are wide chars. Make sure you have single-byte chars, remove any reference to wide chars you have in this small test project to see where the issue starts happening.

Comment: Sir, another question, why I clone a repository from github, it returns: "Received unexpected content-type"?

Comment: It could be for a few different reasons, you may not be passing the right url, or in some cases this can happen for bad credentials. Impossible to know without code and context

Comment: **The code is:**

#include <windows.h>  
#include "include/git2.h"  

#pragma comment(lib, "git2.lib")  

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    git_threads_init();

 git_repository* repo = NULL;
 git_clone_options opts = GIT_CLONE_OPTIONS_INIT;
 int iRetVal;

 opts.bare = true;
 iRetVal = git_clone(&repo, "https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2.git", "C:\\test", &opts);
 if( (iRetVal < 0) && (giterr_last() != NULL) )
 {
        MessageBox(NULL, giterr_last()->message, "gittest", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
 }
 if( repo != NULL )
  git_repository_free(repo);

    git_threads_shutdown();
 return 0;
}

Comment: Sir, the code had posted appending my question. Please help me to have a look. regards.

Comment: That *should* work. Have you tried not using the '.git' at the end of the url? Make sure you're using 0.21. Do you have a proxy or captive portal which might be injecting a response between libgit2 and GitHub?

Comment: I had found the problem, thanks sir.